# PHP. Invalid Signature. При генерации jwt

Tags: php, jwt

Являюсь новичков в php и пытаюсь реализовать простое приложение с регистрацией и авторизацией. Но появляются ошибки при создании jwt. Выводит ошибку синтаксиса jwt-token на сайте, где я произвожу проверку только что сгенерированного токена.

Использую библиотеку php/jwt:

> ссылка на библиотеку https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt

jwt:

> `eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NjIzOTc1MTB9.Tk6Zm-VLoEuVpZ-W44DpKFhhFpRti9Z4lfepEzXmzsMeyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpYXQiOjE2NjIzOTc1MTB9.Tk6Zm-VLoEuVpZ-W44DpKFhhFpRti9Z4lfepEzXmzsM`

```
$key = $_ENV['SECRET_KEY']; // значение: SECRET_CODE
```

мой код php:

```
    <?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../interface/interface.php';

use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Firebase\JWT\Key;

class JWThandler implements IJWThandler
{

    public function getCookie(string $name)
    {

        if (isset($_COOKIE[$name])) {

            return $_COOKIE[$name];
        }

        return "need cookie";
    }

    public function checkToken(string $token)
    {

        return true;
    }

    public function setAccessToken(string $token)
    {

        return true;
    }

    public function setRefreshToken(string $token)
    {
    }

    public function setCookie(string $name, string $value, int $duration)
    {
        setcookie($name, $value, time() + $duration, "/", "", "", true);
    }

    public function createJWT(int $duration)
    {
        $key = $_ENV['SECRET_KEY'];

        $payload = [
            'iat' => time() + 10000
        ];

        $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $key, 'HS256');

        echo $jwt;

        return $jwt;
    }
}
```

Пример ошибки с сайта по проверке jwt:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а если без сайта декодирвать обратно через `decode` ? `JWT::decode($jwt, new Key($key, 'HS256'));` что выводит?

Comment: выдает ошибку декодирования